# HTML select permanent display value?

Tags: javascript, html, css

How would one make a drop down select box always show the same value, rather than the selected value?

Example:

```
<select value="Color">
<option value="blue">Blue</option>
<option value="red">Red</option>
</select>
```

I would like the select box to always show "color" rather than "blue" or "red" when they are selected.

Comment: I want the user to be able to select values (to change the color of selected text) but I'd like the shown value to always be "color"

Comment: I don't think this is possible without JavaScript.

Comment: This should be solved by having a `<label>` outside the `<select>` instead of trying to make the drop down be its own label.

Comment: I am able to  use javascript to achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that you're able to accept JavaScript solutions, as noted in [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28014507/html-select-permanent-display-value/28030934#comment44418603_28014507), I can offer you the following solution that should be somewhat extensible and customisable to your needs.

It could be simplified though, which would probably be of benefit to any (potential) future users:

```
// simple function to uppercase the first letter of a given string,
// if it's a lower-case letter:
// of a given string:
function upperCaseFirst(str) {
    return str.replace(/^[a-z]/, function (firstLetter) {
        return firstLetter.toUpperCase();
    });
}

// as above, but from upper-case to lower-case:    
function lowerCaseFirst(str) {
    return str.replace(/^[A-Z]/, function (firstLetter) {
        return firstLetter.toLowerCase();
    });
}

function showOptionString(opts) {
    /* these are the defaults,
       replace: Boolean, true/false
                true - replaces the option-text with the
                       supplied prefix/suffix strings
                false - wraps the option-text with the
                        supplied prefix/suffix strings
       sentenceCaseOption: Boolean, true/false
                true - lower-cases both the first letter of
                       the option-text, and the first-letter
                       of the option's original text when
                       constructing the new text
                false - maintains both the option-text's case
                       and that of the supplied prefix-string
       separator: String,
                the string with which the option-text should be
                separated from the supplied prefix/suffix
       prefixString: String,
                the text which will precede the option-text (if
                settings.replace is set to false), or which will
                replace the option-text (by default)
       suffixString: String,
                the text which will follow the option-text (if
                settings.replace is set to false), or which will
                replace the option-text (by default)
    var settings = {
        'replace': true,
            'sentenceCaseOption': true,
            'separator': ' ',
            'prefixString': '',
            'suffixString': ''
    };

    // if the user has supplied options:
    if (opts) {
        // we iterate through the properties of the settings object and
        for (var prop in settings) {
            // if the property is of the object itself (not from
            // elsewhere in the prototype chain)
            if (settings.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
                // overwrite the property of the settings object,
                // if that property is not undefined in the supplied
                // options object (otherwise we 'retain' the default):
                settings[prop] = opts[prop] !== undefined ? opts[prop] : settings[prop];
            }
        }
    }

    // having used Function.prototype.call when assigning the
    // the event-handler, 'this' is the <select> element:
    var select = this,
        // retrieving the <option> elements from the <select>
        options = select.options,
        // finding the selected <option>
        selected = options[select.selectedIndex],
        // we use String.prototype.trim() later to remove
        // leading/trailing white-space from the option-text;
        // here we create a regular expression to remove non white-
        // space portions of the supplied separator string.

        // removing leading white-space from the separator
        // ' : ' would become ': '
        leading = settings.separator.replace(/^\s+/, ''),
        // removing trailing white-space from the separator
        // ' : ' would become ' :'
        trailing = settings.separator.replace(/\s+$/, ''),

        // creating a single regular expression, using the 'new RegExp()'
        // constructor which will match the above strings when found
        // at the beginning (leading) or end (trailing) of the
        // option-text:
        trimReg = new RegExp('^' + leading + '|' + trailing + '$', 'g');

    // using forEach to iterate over the array-like NodeList of
    // <option> elements:
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(options, function (opt) {
        // opt is the current <option> of the NodeList over
        // which we're iterating.

        // creating a property on the Node, setting its 'oldValue' property
        // to be equal to its oldValue property or, if not yet set, to its
        // current text:
        opt.oldValue = opt.oldValue || opt.text;

        // setting the text back to its oldValue (this is to revert
        // previously-changed text back to its original form):
        opt.text = opt.oldValue;
    });

    // if settings.replace is true:
    if (settings.replace) {
        // we set the selected-option's text to a string created by
        // joining an Array of the prefixString and suffixString
        // together with the separator string:
        selected.text = [settings.prefixString, settings.suffixString].join(settings.separator);
    } else {
        // otherwise, if sentenceCaseOption is true:
        if (settings.sentenceCaseOption) {
            // do much the same, except we include the option-text's
            // lower-cased oldValue in the string we create:
            selected.text = [settings.prefixString, lowerCaseFirst(selected.oldValue), settings.suffixString].join(settings.separator);
        } else {
            // and, if we don't need/want to sentence-case the
            // option text we do exactly the same as above, but
            // without calling lowerCaseFirst() on the oldValue:
            selected.text = [settings.prefixString, selected.oldValue, settings.suffixString].join(settings.separator);
        }
    }
    // here we get the selected-option's text, trim the
    // leading/trailing white-space from it and replace any
    // remaining portions of the separator that might exist.
    // if settings.sentenceCaseOption is true,
    // we use upperCaseFirst() to upper-case the first-letter,
    // otherwise we do not:
    selected.text = settings.sentenceCaseOption ? upperCaseFirst(selected.text.trim().replace(trimReg, '')) : selected.text.trim().replace(trimReg, '');

}

// a reference to the first <select> element from the document:
var select = document.querySelector('select');

// adding a 'change' event-listener to the <select> element:
select.addEventListener('change', function () {
    // assigning the showOptionString() function as
    // the event-handler, together with Function.prototype.call
    // to pass the <select> element to the function, inside of
    // of which it will be the function's 'this':
    showOptionString.call(this, {
        // setting some of the user-supplied options:
        'prefixString': 'color',
            'suffixString': '',
            'separator': ' - '
    });
});
```

```js
function upperCaseFirst(str) {
  return str.replace(/^[a-z]/, function(firstLetter) {
    return firstLetter.toUpperCase();
  });
}

function lowerCaseFirst(str) {
  return str.replace(/^[A-Z]/, function(firstLetter) {
    return firstLetter.toLowerCase();
  });
}

function showOptionString(opts) {
  var settings = {
    'replace': true,
    'sentenceCaseOption': true,
    'separator': ' ',
    'prefixString': '',
    'suffixString': ''
  };

  if (opts) {
    for (var prop in settings) {
      if (settings.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
        settings[prop] = opts[prop] !== undefined ? opts[prop] : settings[prop];
      }
    }
  }
  var select = this,
    options = select.options,
    selected = options[select.selectedIndex],
    leading = settings.separator.replace(/^\s+/, ''),
    trailing = settings.separator.replace(/\s+$/, ''),
    trimReg = new RegExp('^' + leading + '|' + trailing + '$', 'g');

  Array.prototype.forEach.call(options, function(opt) {
    opt.oldValue = opt.oldValue || opt.text;
    opt.text = opt.oldValue;
  });

  if (settings.replace) {
    selected.text = [settings.prefixString, settings.suffixString].join(settings.separator);
  } else {
    if (settings.sentenceCaseOption) {
      selected.text = [settings.prefixString, lowerCaseFirst(selected.oldValue), settings.suffixString].join(settings.separator);
    } else {
      selected.text = [settings.prefixString, selected.oldValue, settings.suffixString].join(settings.separator);
    }
  }
  selected.text = settings.sentenceCaseOption ? upperCaseFirst(selected.text.trim().replace(trimReg, '')) : selected.text.trim().replace(trimReg, '');

}

var select = document.querySelector('select');

select.addEventListener('change', function() {
  showOptionString.call(this, {
    'prefixString': 'color',
    'suffixString': '',
    'separator': ' - ',
  });
});
```

```html
<select value="Color">
  <option value="blue">Blue</option>
  <option value="red">Red</option>
</select>
```

Note that, while I've answered the question to the best of my ability to meet your use-case and stated requirement, I would argue against replacing the `<option>` text entirely (which is why I offer it as a user-configurable option within the supplied function), since it looks (to the user) as if no change is being made leading to them having to reopen the `<select>` at least once, just to check.

Therefore I'd almost certainly set `replace: false` as a default to the function:

```
function showOptionString(opts) {
  var settings = {
    'replace': false,
    'sentenceCaseOption': true,
    'separator': ' ',
    'prefixString': '',
    'suffixString': ''
  };
  /* ... rest of function ... */
}
```

```js
function upperCaseFirst(str) {
  return str.replace(/^[a-z]/, function(firstLetter) {
    return firstLetter.toUpperCase();
  });
}

function lowerCaseFirst(str) {
  return str.replace(/^[A-Z]/, function(firstLetter) {
    return firstLetter.toLowerCase();
  });
}

function showOptionString(opts) {
  var settings = {
    'replace': false,
    'sentenceCaseOption': true,
    'separator': ' ',
    'prefixString': '',
    'suffixString': ''
  };

  if (opts) {
    for (var prop in settings) {
      if (settings.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
        settings[prop] = opts[prop] !== undefined ? opts[prop] : settings[prop];
      }
    }
  }
  var select = this,
    options = select.options,
    selected = options[select.selectedIndex],
    leading = settings.separator.replace(/^\s+/, ''),
    trailing = settings.separator.replace(/\s+$/, ''),
    trimReg = new RegExp('^' + leading + '|' + trailing + '$', 'g');

  Array.prototype.forEach.call(options, function(opt) {
    opt.oldValue = opt.oldValue || opt.text;
    opt.text = opt.oldValue;
  });

  if (settings.replace) {
    selected.text = [settings.prefixString, settings.suffixString].join(settings.separator);
  } else {
    if (settings.sentenceCaseOption) {
      selected.text = [settings.prefixString, lowerCaseFirst(selected.oldValue), settings.suffixString].join(settings.separator);
    } else {
      selected.text = [settings.prefixString, selected.oldValue, settings.suffixString].join(settings.separator);
    }
  }
  selected.text = settings.sentenceCaseOption ? upperCaseFirst(selected.text.trim().replace(trimReg, '')) : selected.text.trim().replace(trimReg, '');

}

var select = document.querySelector('select');

select.addEventListener('change', function() {
  showOptionString.call(this, {
    'prefixString': 'color',
    'suffixString': '',
    'separator': ' - ',
    'replace': false,
  });
});
```

```html
<select value="Color">
  <option value="blue">Blue</option>
  <option value="red">Red</option>
</select>
```

Or, instead, as a passed-in option, as a UI feature:

```
select.addEventListener('change', function() {
  showOptionString.call(this, {
    'prefixString': 'color',
    'suffixString': '',
    'separator': ' - '
    'replace' : false,
  });
});
```

```js
function upperCaseFirst(str) {
  return str.replace(/^[a-z]/, function(firstLetter) {
    return firstLetter.toUpperCase();
  });
}

function lowerCaseFirst(str) {
  return str.replace(/^[A-Z]/, function(firstLetter) {
    return firstLetter.toLowerCase();
  });
}

function showOptionString(opts) {
  var settings = {
    'replace': true,
    'sentenceCaseOption': true,
    'separator': ' ',
    'prefixString': '',
    'suffixString': ''
  };

  if (opts) {
    for (var prop in settings) {
      if (settings.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
        settings[prop] = opts[prop] !== undefined ? opts[prop] : settings[prop];
      }
    }
  }
  var select = this,
    options = select.options,
    selected = options[select.selectedIndex],
    leading = settings.separator.replace(/^\s+/, ''),
    trailing = settings.separator.replace(/\s+$/, ''),
    trimReg = new RegExp('^' + leading + '|' + trailing + '$', 'g');

  Array.prototype.forEach.call(options, function(opt) {
    opt.oldValue = opt.oldValue || opt.text;
    opt.text = opt.oldValue;
  });

  if (settings.replace) {
    selected.text = [settings.prefixString, settings.suffixString].join(settings.separator);
  } else {
    if (settings.sentenceCaseOption) {
      selected.text = [settings.prefixString, lowerCaseFirst(selected.oldValue), settings.suffixString].join(settings.separator);
    } else {
      selected.text = [settings.prefixString, selected.oldValue, settings.suffixString].join(settings.separator);
    }
  }
  selected.text = settings.sentenceCaseOption ? upperCaseFirst(selected.text.trim().replace(trimReg, '')) : selected.text.trim().replace(trimReg, '');

}

var select = document.querySelector('select');

select.addEventListener('change', function() {
  showOptionString.call(this, {
    'prefixString': 'color',
    'suffixString': '',
    'separator': ' - ',
    'replace' : false,
  });
});
```

```html
<select value="Color">
  <option value="blue">Blue</option>
  <option value="red">Red</option>
</select>
```

References:

- [`Array.protoype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).
- [`Array.protoype.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join).
- [`document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelector).
- [`EventTarget.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener).
- [`for...in` loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty).
- [`Function.prototype.call()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call).
- [`HTMLOptionElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLOptionElement).
- [`HTMLSelectElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement).
- [JavaScript RegularExpressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).
- [`Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty).
- [`RegExp()` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp).
- [`String.prototype.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace).
- [`String.prototype.toLowerCase()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase).
- [`String.prototype.toUpperCase()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toUpperCase).
- [`String.prototype.trim()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trim).

Answer (score -1):

Here is the code:

```
<select>
<option value="color" selected>Color</option>
<option value="blue">Blue</option>
<option value="red">Red</option>
</select>
```

You can add the `selected` attribute to the first `option` which will now be `color` Hope this helps.

Comment: The question is asking how to display "Color" after the user has picked a different option. It isn't asking how to set a default option.